# Warning: Illegal offset type in vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/CategoryRepository.php on line 133

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1.8, repository

I am getting

> Warning: Illegal offset type in
>   vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/CategoryRepository.php on line
>   133

on product details page in **Magento 2.1.8** Which is caused by

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/ListProduct.php(114)

Please refer screenshot - code from ListProduct.php [image: code from ListProduct.php file]

Code from CategoryRepository.php
[image]

Comment: did you try to refresh cache by cache:flush and cache:clean command?

Comment: Yes I had try cache:flush. Still getting same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the same issue in 2.1.8. Though for me it only occured when the FPC was enabled. It seems to be caused by:

```
$this->setCategoryId(current($categories->getIterator()));
```

in `vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/ListProduct.php`. An issue that was fixed in Magento 2.2.0. New code is:

```
$this->setCategoryId(current($categories->getIterator())->getId());
```

Upgrading to **2.2.x** should resolve the issue. If that's not an option you could also try disabling FPC.

Comment: If I disable FPC then what about performance?

Comment: It'll obviously have effect on your shop's performance. It's up to you to decide which way to go. Another option would be to temporarily disable all blocks that use ListProduct.php until you can upgrade (related products/upsell/etc). That's not something that I can judge for you.